# Make an alert using twitter's bootstrap disappears after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to learn twitter's bootstrap CSS framework to make some alerts to the users, I want, after showing the alert to the user, the alert disappears after 3 seconds have elapsed. I make this code, but does not work, can not close the alert, and do not understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Alert in boostrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert-message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove(); 
                });
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body >
        <br><br>
        <div class="container">
                <h1>This is a test</h1>
                <div id="alert_message" class="alert" style="width:200px" >
                    <span class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</span>
                    <span><strong>Atention!</strong> Responsive Design with Twitter Bootstrap.</span>
                </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

ps: im newbie in the art of web programming, have a little patience if the question or error is very obvious or stupid. Thank you very much to all

Comment: ,i believe what you are looking for is toastr jquery plugin or pnotify plugin.Do check them out. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, you're missing jQuery library, include it before `bootstrap.min.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, it should be `#alert_message` instead of `.alert-message`:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  $("#alert_message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
}, 3000);
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://bootply.com/107923)**

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here `$(".alert-message")` with this you are saying that you have a class with the name "alert-message" but you don't, you have and id not a class so it would be `$("#alert_message")`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">The message was sent</div>

<script>
$(".alert").delay(4000).slideUp(200, function() {
    $(this).alert('close');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Out [Bootstrap Notify](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/) it's an extremely versatile alerts plugin using dependencies of jQuery and Bootstrap. It's available under MIT licence.

Calling a new notification is as easy as `$.notify('Hello World')` but you can get as complex as you like, add images, icons, hyperlinks, resize it, restyle it.